# how to create multiple columns based on another column value in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, csv

Need some help with pandas. Have a CSV file like below.

```
 id,kt,kn
 872,email,c@email.com
 872,phone,123456
 991,email,a@email.com
 991,phone,1234
 999,email,b@email.com
 999,phone,12345
 999,bph,23456789
```

Need to change this to like below.

```
 id,email,phone,bph
 872,c@email.com,123456,NA
 991,a@email.com,1234,NA
 999,b@email.com,12345,23456789
```

Basically, the value under `kt` column should become a new column and corresponding row `kn` should become row value under that column.

Comment: `df.pivot(index='id', columns='kt', values='kn').reset_index()`

Comment: appreciate your quick response.